# Is there a web image gallery generator that will run on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a web image gallery generator that will run on Ubuntu?

What I'm looking for is something that will take a set of images, create a Javascript image gallery that I can then upload and embed on a web site I run. Ideally embed onto a Google Blogger blog as well. I can place the pictures on a folder on my own web server, or elswhere.

There are [online services that do this](http://www.quickgallery.com/), but they require that I host the pictures on other sites, and it gets to be a bit of a hassle having so many sites and logins and hosting services involved. It would be nice if I could just bundle everything up and put it on my web site, completely self contained.

I came across [this](http://flash-gallery.com/gallery-builder/), but it requires Adobe Air, and, not only do I not really want to get involved with Adobe, they stopped supporting Air for Linux after version 2.6.

I'm hoping for something fairly user friendly. It's not just me who will potentially build galleries.

I found [an old post from 2005 on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-104216.html) mentiong gThumb, but, unless I'm missing something, it doesn't create a slideshow style presentation, just creates a grid of pictures. Or at the least, the options for customizing the look and feel of the gallery is very limited, and not in keeping with modern looks and feels.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

I use [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb). It's in the default Ubuntu installation.

Just select the folder of photos you want to use and go to File --> Export To --> Web Album

[image]